# How make input radio value as number?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying do arithmetic operation using radio button (just an experiment)

browser returns value NaN

```js
let num1 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('#number1:checked'));
let num2 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('#number2:checked'));

function addTambah() {
  result = num1 + num2;
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<p>number : </p>
<input type="radio" name="number1" id="number11" value="1">
<label for="radio">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="number1" id="number12" value="2">
<label for="radio">2</label>
<p> number 2 : </p>
<input type="radio" name="number2" id="number21" value="1">
<label for="radio">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="number2" id="number22" value="2">
<label for="radio">2</label>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="addTambah()">Add</button>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an array-like nodelist. You can't parseInt on a nodelist. Try `querySelector` instead, particularly if you're targeting a element with an id.

Comment: @Andy same, its return Nan

Comment: your ids should be unique

Comment: Here is a working version using ES6 and recommended methods https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ro2891s4/

`const checked = document.querySelectorAll('[name^=number]:checked'); const sum = checked.length ? [...checked].map(fld => +fld.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b) : 0;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to get the value of the checked radio buttons inside the function & secondly every dom element should have unique id. Also use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`

```js
function addTambah() {
  let add = document.querySelector('input[name="number1"]:checked').value;
  let add1 = document.querySelector('input[name="number2"]:checked').value;
  const result = parseInt(add, 10) + parseInt(add1, 10)
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<p>number : </p>
<input type="radio" checked name="number1" id="number1" value="1">
<label for="radio">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="number1" id="number2" value="2">
<label for="radio">2</label>
<p> number 2 : </p>
<input type="radio" name="number2" id="number3" value="1">
<label for="radio">1</label>
<input type="radio" checked name="number2" id="number4" value="2">
<label for="radio">2</label>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="addTambah()">Add</button>
```

Comment: yeah, i just realize my code have same id

Comment: Your code gives error. You need `document.querySelector('input[name="number1"]:checked')?.value` since OP allows a click when nothing is checked. anyway a huge dupe

Comment: thanks, u right my codes give error when radio not clicked. thx again @mplungjan

Comment: @arcahyadi use `checked` attribute and make default checked